electron 27 version. Configure the configuration of the HTTPS web API to work properly under HTTP
BrowserWindow Configuration
hi, This is the BrowserWindow configuration I used, and even though I set the webSecurity property to false, it still cannot solve the problem of using MediaDevices: getUserMedia.
I want to use the MediaDevices: getUserMedia API through the loadURL of Electron, but it needs to be used in a local area network environment and in an HTTP protocol IP address environment. Is there any way Electron can configure MediaDevices: getUserMedia API to use this API in HTTP? What content needs to be configured? I saw in MDN that this can only be used under the HTTPS protocol.
I am using the Win10 system,
Electron accessing services through loadURL is used on the local area network and accessed through IP.
I expect the Electron to have configuration properties that support the use of MediaDevices: getUserMedia API under HTTP, as this is a necessary prerequisite for my business needs.
